# How to display multiple PDFs

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

The below code can display 1 pdf document, and this app can accept multiple uploads of pdfs, but how can I display multiple pdfs in 1 viewer (if each pdf has 1 page, and I've uploaded 3 documents, I expect to see 3 pages in that viewer)? Is it possible or do I need to look at the dynamic UI to display them in different viewer?

If the below code is not working for you, please ensure that you have a `www` folder where you keep your `app.R` and restart RStudio.

### EDIT:

Thanks for heds1's answer which can view the pdf in different viewers, however not sure if someone knows how to view them in 1 viewer instead of multiple? Will keep the post open for a few more days to see if it's possible at all.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Testing File upload"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file_input', 'upload file ( . pdf format only)', accept = c('.pdf'),multiple = T)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("pdfview")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  observe({
    req(input$file_input)
    
    file.copy(input$file_input$datapath,"www", overwrite = T)
    
    output$pdfview <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="0.pdf")
    })
    
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Just add multiple viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not sure that you'll always have three files to view, a dynamic UI would be best. Here's an example (I've ignored the file upload aspect, to focus on the dynamic UI part):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(uiOutput("pdfview_ui"))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    # get pdf files in directory
    files <- list.files(path = "www")
    
    # loop over files to create iframes
    lapply(files, function(file) {
        output[[file]] <- renderUI({
            tags$iframe(style= "height:600px; width:100%", src = file)
        })
    })
    
    # loop over files to render the iframes
    output$pdfview_ui <- renderUI({
        lapply(files, function(file) {
            uiOutput(file)
        })
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Have your PDF files in the `www` folder, and hit `Run App` in RStudio rather than running the code directly, otherwise it won't source the PDF's properly.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple pdfs in one viewer? Or does it have to create multiple viewer as in your example? Thanks

Comment: No idea sorry. But I doubt it would be easy, if it's possible at all.

Comment: Will accept your answer for this one. Can you also have a look at another closely related question I raised please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68399827/r-shiny-import-multiple-pdfs-and-view-them-one-by-one-using-actionbutton