# R Shiny import multiple PDFs and view them one by one using actionButton

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

I have the below app that can view one pdf after import. However I want to be able to import multiple PDFs (this can already be done), and click the `Next PDF` actionButton to view the next PDF. All the way till the last imported PDF, how can I do that?

If the below code is not working to view one pdf, please ensure you have a `www` folder in the same directory of your `app.R`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Testing File upload"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file_input', 'upload file ( . pdf format only)',
                accept = c('.pdf'),multiple = T),
      actionButton("next_pdf", "Next PDF")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("pdfview")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  observe({
    req(input$file_input)
    
    file.copy(input$file_input$datapath,"www", overwrite = T)
    
    output$pdfview <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(style="height:1200px; width:100%", src="0.pdf")
    })
    
  })
  
  
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a solution! I use `reactiveVal` for variable `x`, and each time the actionButton is clicked, `x` will increase 1. On that basis, I can view the PDF one by one by specifying datapath[]. It can be very useful for people with multiple pdf files.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Testing File upload"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file_input', 'upload file ( . pdf format only)',
                accept = c('.pdf'),multiple = T),
      tableOutput("files"),
      actionButton("next_pdf", "Next PDF"),
      textOutput("testing")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("pdfview")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  x = reactiveVal(1)
  
  output$files <- renderTable({input$file_input})
  
  observeEvent(input$file_input,{
    
    file.copy(input$file_input$datapath[1],"www", overwrite = T)
    
    output$pdfview <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(style="height:1200px; width:100%", src="0.pdf")
    })
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$next_pdf,{
      x(x()+1) 
    
    file.rename(input$file_input$datapath[x()], "0.pdf")
    file.copy("0.pdf","www", overwrite = T)
    
    output$pdfview <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(style="height:1200px; width:100%", src="0.pdf")
    })
    
    output$testing = renderText(x())
  })
  
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```